# Delegate method returning weird result

Tags: c#

```
        delegate bool CheckList(int lowIndex, List<int> list);
    public BO2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void BO2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<int> randList = new List<int>() { 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        CheckList HasDuplicate = (int lowIndex, List<int> list) =>
            {
                Predicate<int> criteria = x => x == lowIndex;
                int topIndex = list.FindIndex(criteria);
                List<int> duplicateList = new List<int>(list);

                for (int i = topIndex; i < (list.Count - topIndex); i++)
                {
                    if (list[i] == duplicateList[i])
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                return false;
            };

        MessageBox.Show("Has copy: " + HasDuplicate.Invoke(5, randList));
```

I'm trying to make an delegate function to see if **List** has two equivalent values. If it has, the function will return true, otherwise false. I coded that function in 8 minutes just for testing purposes, since this method would be useful for me on some cases, that's why errors may occur easily :'D

**PROBLEM:** The function simply always returns true, if you have pair of 7 in **randList**, result is always same, true.

**NOTE:** If you're wondering what is the meaning of `lowIndex`, it specifies the index to start seaching from **List**. Example: `lowIndex = 5`, the function will find the index of 5 in the list and start searhing for duplicates after that point. :)

I wan't to know why it returns true every time, I do not want a workaround, either the answer & workaround or only answer.

Regards, TuukkaX.

Comment: Hopefully I'm not missing something but you're initializing `duplicatedList` with `list`. This means they will have the same elements and, because of this,  `list[i] == duplicateList[i]` is always true.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi I looked at that once, but something changed my thoughts and I thought that it's ok :'D Go ahead and post an answer of what you said since it's correct. I figured out a way to solve the whole thing with what you've noticed, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: If you use the `Distinct` extension to create a new list with without any duplicates, the `Count()`'s of the 2 lists will be the same if there aren't any duplicates.

Comment: @ryanyuyu I highly doubt that this is an copy of that question, I wasn't trying to delete duplicate, I was checking if there exists one.

Comment: @TuukkaX It was my mistake.  I was searching via the dup screen for a related question, and I accidentally hit enter...  And there is no way to retract the flag...I'll delete the auto comment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing `duplicatedList` with `list`. This means they will have the same elements and, because of this, `list[i] == duplicateList[i]` is always true

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I made to solve the problem if anyone needs it, since I didn't provide it earlier.

```
            delegate bool CheckList(int lowIndex, List<int> list);
            CheckList HasDuplicate = (List<dynamic> list, int item) =>
            {
                if (list.Contains(item))
                {
                    list.Remove(item);
                    return list.Contains(item) ? true : false;
                }

                return false;
            };
```

The **Type** can be any type basically, **dynamic** for example.